# Наращение перед словом "курс"

Tags: наращение

Нужно ли наращение: 1-й курс, 2-го курса и т. д.?
В Грамоте пишут 1-й класс, но примеров со словом "курс" нет. И в Нацкорпусе все пишут без наращения.

Comment: _Рад: И в Нацкорпусе все пишут без наращения..._ === Все??? Да Вы что?! См. примеры из Нацкорпуса: http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0 === http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81

Comment: Я нашел только один вариант с наращением (наверное плохо искал). В любом случае без наращения там вариантов гораздо больше. А я считал тексты в Нацкорпусе "безгрешными"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишите с наращением, не сомневайтесь.
Необходимость наращения определяется не существительным, которое считают, а тем, что прилагательное порядковое.

Единственное исключение (не всеми признаваемое) - слово "год", при обозначении календарного года. В этом случае наращение обычно опускают.

"Курс" же ничем не лучше всех остальных существительных. Хотя мне понятны мотивы, по которым это наращение хотят опустит (тут оно как имя собственное выступает), пододоное исключение нигде в нормативных источниках, судя по всему, не фиксируется.